# Unable to access local server via public IP on port 80 and 443

Tags: http, nginx, https, port, nat

I have a public IP address in the range 82.x.x.x, and a local IP address in the range 172.x.x.x. My local server is configured to work with the local IP address. I set up NAT settings on my Keenetic router to forward ports 22, 80, and 443 from the public IP address to my local IP address. Port 22 works fine, but ports 80 and 443 do not. However, when I access the domain name "texnopark.keenetic.pro" that I created on the router, I see the "Welcome to nginx" page. When I try to access port 80 using my public IP address, it doesn't work.

My local server is an HPE ProLient DL380 GEN10 running Ubuntu Server 22.04.

I would like to understand why I am unable to access my server using port 80 and 443 via the public IP address. Any help would be appreciated

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.16.0.217  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 172.16.3.255
    ether d0:67:26:d0:5f:d4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 490060  bytes 115094106 (115.0 MB)
    RX errors 1  dropped 27187  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 47284  bytes 5623287 (5.6 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 16
```

netplane

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
    eno3:
      dhcp4: true
    eno4:
      dhcp4: true
```

iLO

```
IPv4 Summary
DHCPv4 Status
Disabled
Address
172.16.0.217
Subnet Mask
255.255.224.0
Default Gateway
172.16.3.255
```